# Split cell contents by capital letters and paste result into multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have a cell that has a name, eg; "John Smith".

I want to split the name into two or more pieces (depending on middle names) and paste them into another cell.

```vb
Private Sub Splitnames_Click()
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet: Set WS1 = Worksheets("sheet1")
    Dim WS2 As Worksheet: Set WS2 = Worksheets("sheet2")
    MyValue = InputBox("Please enter employee name...", "Import employee", "Enter employee name here...")
    WS1.Range("E44").Value = MyValue
    Dim FoundCell As Range: Set FoundCell = WS2.Range("A2:A1000").Find(WS1.Range("E44").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
    If FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        Set FoundCell = Nothing
        Set WS1 = Nothing
        Set WS2 = Nothing
        MsgBox "No Employee found!"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Name = FoundCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=16).Value
        SplitWords = Left(Name , 1)
        For I = 2 To Len(Trim(Name ))
            If (Asc(Mid(Name , I, 1)) > 64) And _
               (Asc(Mid(Name , I, 1)) < 91) And _
               (Mid(Name , I - 1, 1) <> " ") Then _
                SplitWords = SplitWords & " "
            SplitWords = SplitWords & Mid(Name , I, 1)
            WS1.Range("C19") = SplitWords
        Next
    End If
    Set FoundCell = Nothing
    Set WS1 = Nothing
    Set WS2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

How do I paste the results into multiple cells?

I need a way to paste result in Sheet1, Cell C19 then C20 then C21 and so forth.

Comment: Please edit your question to include, as **text** which can be copy/pasted and example of data showing the variable ways the names might be entered, along with your desired results, would be helpful in figuring out a good solution.

Comment: just saying you have no idea what the code is doing, and pasting any code that has not a lot do to with your problem, does nocht show a lot of effort from your side. Search for something like excel vba split text each space

Answer (score 1):

This code splits the name based on where spaces are (so not exactly based on capital letters per the title of the question). To use this, remove all your code from the line `SplitWords = Left(Name , 1)` to `Next` (inclusive) and replace it with:

```
    Dim nameArray As Variant
    nameArray = Split(Name, " ")
    WS1.Range("C19:C23").ClearContents
    If UBound(nameArray) >= 0 Then
        WS1.Range("C19").Resize(UBound(nameArray) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(nameArray)
    End If
```

This code assumes that your `Name` variable correctly has a name set into it ... I can't check that as I don't have a copy of the data in `sheet1` and `sheet2`.

It also assumes that no name ever has more than 5 individual words ... if it does, increase the number of rows cleared in the `WS1.Range("C19:C23").ClearContents` line. This ensures that no individual words are left-over from previously processed names (if the previously processed name contains more individual words).

Comment: Why not simply referring to the same resized range for `.ClearContents`? If you'd envelop it into a `With` statement you could even abbreviate it to `.ClearContents` and `.Value2 = ...` following the `If Ubound(...) >=0` condition check. @JohnM

Comment: Because the `.ClearContents` is clearing whatever was put in those cells the *previous* time the code ran

Comment: mmh, All depending on OP's needs which may be rest unrevealed (*"have no idea what im doing lol"*)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answers, ended up going down a different route using ". " as a separator. im sure it could be modified to capital letters somehow if someone wants too see the code i came up with below;

```
Dim EmployeeSplit() As String, Employee As String, EI As Variant, EN As Integer
        Employee = FoundCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=25).Value
        If Employee = "" Then
        Else
        'Use Split function to divide up the component parts of the string
        EmployeeSplit= Split(Employee, ". ", 4)
        i = 0
        For N = 0 To UBound(EmployeeSplit)
        i = i + 2
        'Place each split into the first column of the worksheet
    WS4.Range("F" & 58 + i).Value = Replace(EmployeeSplit(N) & ". ", ". . ", ". ")
        If WS4.Range("F" & 58 + i).Value = ". " Then
        WS4.Range("F" & 58 + i).Value = ""
        End If
        Next N
        End If
```

i used i = i + 2 because im using merged cells so i need it placed in every second cell.